# How can I use proved goals of locale interpretation to prove the remaining ones

Tags: isabelle

I define a strict order locale as follows:

```
locale strict_order =
fixes ls::"'a set ⇒ 'a set ⇒ bool"
assumes 
  irrefl:"¬ ls a a" and
  trans:"ls a c ∧ ls c g ⟹ ls a g" and 
  asym:"ls a c ⟹ ¬ ls c a"
```

Then, I declare a type as interpretation of strict_order

```
interpretation nest:strict_order "op ≪"
proof
 fix a
 show "¬ a ≪ a"
 proof (rule contra, auto) 
  ....
 qed
 next
 fix a c g
 assume a:"a ≪ c ∧ c ≪ g"
 show " a ≪ g" 
 proof -
  (* uses the fact that ¬ a<<a *)
```

The proof "trans" property for type nest needs at some point "irrefl" property which has been successfully proved inside the interpretation block. How can I label and use it? Or there is no way but moving it outside the interpretation block?

Thanks.

Comment: Andreas ninja'd me, but here are two other remarks that I have: 1. `ls a c ∧ ls c g ⟹ ls a g` is expressed more idiomatically as `ls a c ⟹ ls c g ⟹ ls a g`. The two statements are logically equivalent, but the second is much easier to use in Isabelle if you do Isar proofs or want to instantiate the theorem with `OF`.

Comment: 2. I get the warning ‘Introduced fixed type variable(s): `'b` in `"a__"`’ at the `show` statements, so you probably do as well. When this happens, it is a good idea to provide explicit types for the fixed variables. To do that, you can replace your `op ≪` in the interpretation with a `op ≪ :: 'a set ⇒ _` and then replace your `fix a` with a `fix a :: "'a set"` etc.

Comment: You are right, types for fixed variables are needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you state a fact with `show`, you can name it just like with `have`, e.g., `show irrefl: "¬ a ≪ a"`. However, `next` drops everything that you have proven so far, so you have to avoid `next`. Conceptually, next corresponds to closing a block and opening a new one, i.e., `next` essentially means `} {`.
Hence, you could write something like the following:

```
proof
  { fix a
    show "¬ a ≪ a"
    proof (rule contra, auto) .... qed }
  note irrefl = this
  { fix a c g
    assume a: "a ≪ c ∧ c ≪ g"
    show "a ≪ g" 
    proof - ... (* can reference irrefl *) qed }
qed
```

Note that you can name the irreflexivity law only after closing the block, because you want the fixed `a` being generalised, which only happens upon export from the block. If you are using Isabelle2016 or later, you can write the cases more concisely using `for` and `if` clauses. This saves you all the boilerplate with `}` and `{`.

```
proof
  show irrefl: "¬ a ≪ a" for a
  proof (rule contra, auto) .... qed

  show "a ≪ g" if a: "a ≪ c ∧ c ≪ g" for a c g
  proof - ... (* can reference irrefl *) qed
qed
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm when next is removed.